# What's the right property for sections in the structure sheaf of the spectrum of a ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* one reads that

> For an open set $U \subseteq Spec A$,
> we define $\mathscr{O}(U)$ to be the set of functions $s: U \rightarrow \displaystyle\coprod_{\mathfrak{p}\in U} A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ such that $s(\mathfrak{p}) \in A_{\mathfrak{p}}$
> for each $\mathfrak{p}$, and such that $s$ is locally a quotient of elements of $A$: to be precise, we require that for each $\mathfrak{p} \in U$ there is a neighborhood $V$ of $\mathfrak{p}$, contained in $U$, and elements $a, f \in A$, such that for each $\mathfrak{q} \in V$, $f \notin \mathfrak{q}$, and $s(q) = \frac{a}{f}$ in $A_{\mathfrak{q}}$.

Does Hartshorne mean a neighborhood $V$ or an open neighborhood $V$? I'm not familiar with the author's conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter. Here *neighborhood* and *open neighborhood* are interchangeable, they lead to equivalent definitions.